# How to properly render html table from recursive structure

Tags: html, angular, html-table

How to properly render html table from recursive structure in Angular?

Here is my try: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gitter-usj76r

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <table>    
    <recursivecomponent [elems]="data"></recursivecomponent>
  </table>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent  {
  data = [{
    name: "Root",
    children: [{
       name: "Level 1",
       children: [{
         name: "Level 2",
         children: []
       }]
    }]
  }];
}
```

**recursive.component.ts**

```
import {Component, Input} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: 'recursivecomponent',
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="let el of elems;">
     <tr><td>{{el.name}}</td><td>Other cell</td></tr>
     <recursivecomponent [elems]="el.children"></recursivecomponent>
    </div>
  `
})
export class RecursiveComponent {
  @Input() elems: any[];  
}
```

Desired output:

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>Root</td><td>Other cell</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Level 1</td><td>Other cell</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Level 2</td><td>Other cell</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Yes, I did put a link in the description. If it is not noticeable by human eye, how should I formulate my description (so others can see it clearly)?

Comment: It's always best to include any relevant code in the question itself, rather than a third-party site. SO is about creating a lasting library of good questions and answers. As such, if "stackblitz.com" was to go out of business, this question wouldn't help anyone else.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I see. I added most important code parts directly within the problem description.

Comment: I had made an edit to remove the "snippet" feature from the TypeScript code, since clicking the Run code snippet buttons on those did nothing interesting (or just threw exceptions). Your later edit overwrite that (no problem; it's your question). You can just paste code, select it and press Ctrl-K or the code button (looks like `{}`) for those. Now that they're in there, you can also just edit your question and delete the comments beginning with `<!-- begin snippet` and `<!-- end snippet`.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Sorry, I have overwritten it unintentionally. I fixed it (I think).
It is great that you care so much about the quality of content!